# send notification to all tokens

Tags: android, firebase, api, notifications

When I want to send Notification to all devices I retrieve all tokens of devices in List and try to send notification to all devices with this List but that work for just the first device's token

- So can I use for loop to send notification to all tokens or there is better way?
- And if I used for loop should I put this process in separate thread?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to send a notification to multiple devices. Looping through all of the tokens isn't needed. Firebase provides a way called `Topic Messaging`.

For example you can subscribe all your devices to a topic called `All` and then message the `All` topic.

Here is the documentation:
[Firebase Topic Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging)